# Check register form without redirecting?

Tags: ajax, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I'm working with passport to register users. Before they register the user also must answer a few questions which save to their profile. The answered are stored in Vars.

My problem is if the user has an issue while submitting the form (example: the user name is taken) The page redirects back and the data from the questions is lost. How would I go about checking to make sure the form is good before redirecting anywhere?

I tried this but so far I cant get it to do what I need it to do:

```
   $(function() {
                $("#checkForm").on("submit", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: $(this).attr("action"),
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            alert('do something to check form?')
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            alert('Form is good now register user?')
                            $("#message").hide();
                            $("#response").html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

Comment: just validate your fields , if all fields are clean(angular pun) then you can safely submit. Namely for every field use a boolean array , validate then activate each index. then loop through if all are true then your form is safe to submit.

Comment: @Caspain The problem I cant figure out is how to check if the user has been taken before it reloads?

Answer (score 1):

You can send a json response from the server to check if any any errors are present.
Example json response

```
{error: true, message: 'User already exists'}
{error: false, message:'Account created successfully'}
```

Then in ajax you can add

```
dataType:'json'
```

Then in success message check response

```
if(response.error){}else{}
```

Comment: Thanks @curious_coder! Where would I put this code? In the function above or in my app.post code?

Comment: Which code are you referring to? Example json response?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell me where each part goes. Little confused

Comment: Without server side code I cannot help you. For example paste the lines which accepts user registration.

Answer (score 0):

Store user answers in local storage. After successful registration clear storage and redirect to next page. After failure redirect back to form page (check existence of user answers in local storage) and fill user answers.

Example of Passport endpoint:

```
app.post('/form', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                                    failureRedirect: '/form' }));
```

Without redirecting:

Create user searching endpoint. Call it before form submission.